# Drag and Drop Unity

Tags: c#, unity2d

Estoy empezando con Unity en el desarrollo de un simulador para Smartphones tanto para Android como Ios, es básicamente un drag and drop de objetos para simular acciones. he seguido algunos tutoriales de movimiento de objetos y acciones pero necesito que este sea touch y de eso no he podido encontrar nada. Bueno todo esto quiero que sea en un ambiente 2D, y para el objeto uso las propiedades de *RigidBody 2D* y *CirculeCollider 2D*

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed;
    public Text counText; 
    public Text Wintext;

    private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    private int count;



    void Start()
    {
        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
        count = 0;
        SetCountText ();
        Wintext.text = "";
    }



    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");
        Vector2 movment = new Vector2 (moveHorizontal, moveVertical);
        rb2d.AddForce (movment * speed);
    } 


    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("PickUp"))
        {
            other.gameObject.SetActive (false);
            count = count + 1;
            SetCountText ();
        }
    }

    void SetCountText ()
    {
        counText.text = "count: " + count.ToString ();
        if (count >= 7) 
        {
            Wintext.text = "you win!";
        }   
    }
}
```

Hasta ahora eso es lo que tengo para el movimiento pero como lo puedo hacer para que reconozca el touch de los celulares?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar como tú bien has dicho "Touch", aquí tienes un pequeño ejemplo sacado de la API de Unity:

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {

    // touchCount devuelve el número de dedos sobre la pantalla
    // GetTouch(0).phase devuelve el estado del primer dedo registrado
}
```

Solo tienes que leerte un poco la API para encontrar más información de los "Touch" y sus fases. Aquí tienes unos links de la API de Unity que te servirán:

[touchCount](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-touchCount.html)

[GetTouch](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html)

Investiga esto y si ves que aun así no te aclaras intento ayudarte.

[EDITADO]

```
private bool isDragging;

void Start() {

  isDragging = false;
}

void Update() {

  if (Input.touchCount != 1) { isDragging = false; }

  if (!isDragging) {

    // tu código para coger un objeto
    isDragging = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: bueno segui los ejemplos y lei documentacion pero tengo varios "bugs" al pasar sobre otro sprites o cosas asi.

Comment: ¿Te está cogiendo los demás objetos al pasar sobre ellos? Danos detalles.

Comment: si exactamente eso.

Comment: Claro, supongo que lo que quieres es que cuando tengas uno cogido ya no coja más, tan usa una variable de control como por ejemplo un **bool** que cuando cojas algo lo "seteas" a _true_ y cuando lo sueltes vuelves a ponerlo en _false_, es decir, mientras esté en _true_ no puedes coger ningún objeto más.

Comment: tienes algun ejemplo o documentación de eso porque soy nuevo en unity y no entiendo muy bien cómo realizar ese tipo de acciones.

Comment: Te he editado la primera respuesta, pero no es la solución completa, te paso un link con un ejemplo muy bueno de un foro de Unity: [Drag&Drop](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/600578/dragging-an-object-by-touch.html)